# how to disable jinja2 template from printing undefine values in YAML

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

How can I avoid jinja2+python from printing the line that has no 'values' in YAML ('key' : 'values').

Let's say I have  a list of variable in .yaml file. Eg:

```
- Fruit : Orange
- Color : Red
- Food : Noodle
```

And I have a template which get the data input from yaml file. Eg:-

```
- set fruit {{FRUIT}}
- set color {{COLOR}}
- set food {{FOOD}}
```

The result will print as: -

```
set fruit Orange
set color Red
set food Noodle
```

But, if one or more of yaml data is not define (`Color :` ), why it's print the line with that variable to None (`set color None`)? How can I just ignore the line that has no 'values'?.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out lines with empty values in a [if statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if):

```
{% if FRUIT %}
- set fruit {{FRUIT}}
{% endif %}
{% if COLOR %}
- set color {{COLOR}}
{% endif %}
{% if FOOD %}
- set food {{FOOD}}
{% endif %}
```

Or of you have a dict with keys/values you can use it in a [loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) to make it more compact. For example:

```
dict_of_items = {'fruit': 'Orange', 'color': 'Red', 'food': 'Noodle'}
```

Then:

```
{% for key, value in dict_of_items.iteritems() %}
- set {{key}} {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I have a lot more statement that need to be checked. What Is the proper ways to do it?

Comment: Added an example. The proper way is to have a dict of items, and use a loop to generate the yaml file. If you need to keep the order of the items, then use collections.OrderedDict.